# .Net Programming Language

Tags: .net, oracle, provider

I want to login to the oracle db as a system admin, and I am specifying DBA privilege as SYSDBA in connection string and I am getting this error:

**Keyword not supported: 'dba privilege'**

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: .NET is not a programming language, you do not want to connect to your database as the DBA from your application, and, well, I don't know.

Comment: Post your connection string please.

Answer (score 4):

straight from [oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featConnecting.htm):

Privileged Connections

Oracle allows database administrators to connect to Oracle Database with either SYSDBA or SYSOPER privileges. This is done through the DBA Privilege attribute of the ConnectionString property.

The following example connects scott/tiger as SYSDBA:

```
// C#

using System;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; 

class PrivilegedConnectionSample
{
  static void Main()
  {
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

    //Connect scott/tiger as SYSDBA   
    con.ConnectionString = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;" + 
      "DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;Data Source=oracle;";
    con.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + con.ServerVersion);

    // Close and Dispose OracleConnection object
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
  }
}
```

Here's another source that has different connection strings for the various providers:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle